# Microsoft Sharepoint 2010-Connecting to a remote site and fetching changelogs

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-office, office365

My problem is simple. I have a registered Sharepoint site/domain (say https://secretText-my.sharepoint.com/personal/blabla) and I want to fetch the changelogs as described here [Sharepoint Change log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb417456)

So my question boils down to >>> How can I use this Changelog API to fetch data for a remote Sharepoint site?

How can I achieve this? I have tried Client Object Model and everything related but my goal is to use [Sharepoint Change log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb417456).

I am hoping for something like,

```
         using (ClientContext ctx = ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedContext("https://secretText-my.sharepoint.com/personal/blabla"))
         {  
            if (ctx != null)
            {
                ctx.Load(ctx.Web); // Query for Web
                ctx.ExecuteQuery(); // Execute

                ctx.Load(ctx.Site);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery(); 

                SPSite site = new SPSite(ctx.Site.Id);
                SPContentDatabase db = site.ContentDatabase;
                // Get the first batch of changes, 
                SPChangeCollection changes = db.GetChanges();
                //USE this 'site' object to fetch the change logs
                .
                .
                .
```

My aim is to somehow instantiate this **SPSite** object which would then help me get the data I want. Although this code seems a bit too ambitious(or totally wrong) but please don't hold it against me, I couldn't find any solution to this.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of Google searches and after reading so many answers, I have come to know that it isn't possible to connect to a remote Sharepoint server through the Server API. As that API works only when SP server is on the same network (same machine or intranet)

The only solution is to use Client Object Model. It provides(maps) quite a lot operations that the Server API gives.

To connect to the remote site I have used the samples provided at the MSDN site for Client Object Model.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147177.aspx)